# Unable to parse data correctly in BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

Below is a snippet of the code I am using in order to parse data off a webpage

```
    link1 = "https://www.codechef.com/status/" + sys.argv[1] + "?sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=29&status=15&handle=&Submit=GO"
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    response = opener.open(link1)
    s = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
    l = soup.findAll('tr',{'class' : 'kol'})
```

Here is the URL of an example page that gets stored in the variable `link1`
https://www.codechef.com/status/CIELAB?sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=29&status=15&handle=&Submit=GO

Now, the problems is that the variable l always gets an empty list even though there are entries in the table generated by the HTML tags I am trying to find.

Please help me out with this.

**EDIT**

Complete Code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import HTMLParser
import requests
html_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()


link = "https://www.codechef.com/status/"+sys.argv[1]+"?sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=29&status=15&handle=&Submit=GO"
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(link)
s = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
try:
    l = soup.findAll('div',{'class' : 'pageinfo'})
    for x in l:
        str_val =  str(x.contents)
    pos = str_val.find('of')
    i = pos+3
    x = 0
    while i < len(str_val):
        if str_val[i] >= str(0) and str_val[i] <= str(9):
            x = x*10 + int(str_val[i])
        i += 1
except:
    x = 1

print x
global lis
lis =  list()
break_loop = 0
for i in range(0,x):
    print i
    if break_loop == 1:
        break
    if i == 0:
        link1 = link
    else:
        link1 = "https://www.codechef.com/status/"+sys.argv[1]+"?page="+str(i)+"&sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=29&status=15&handle=&Submit=GO"
    # opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    # opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    # response = opener.open(link1)
    useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
    req = requests.get(link1, headers={'User-Agent': useragent})
    # s = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
    l = soup.findAll('tr',{'class' : r'\"kol\"'})
    print l
    for val in l:
        lang_val = val.find('td',{'width' : '70'})
        lang = lang_val.renderContents().strip()
        print lang
        try:
            data = val.find('td',{'width' : '51'})
            data_val = data.span.contents
        except:
            break
        if lang != 'PHP':
            break_loop = 1
            break
        if len(data_val) > 1 and html_parser.unescape(data_val[2]) != '100':
            continue
        str_val =  str(val.td.contents)
        p = 0
        j = 0
        while p < len(str_val):
            if str_val[p] >= str(0) and str_val[p] <= str(9):
                j = j*10 + int(str_val[p])
            p += 1
        lis.insert(0,str(j))
if len(lis) > 0:
    try:
        os.mkdir(sys.argv[1]+"_php")
    except:
        pass
count  = 1
for data in lis:
    cmd = "python parse_data_final.py "+data+" > "+sys.argv[1]+"_php/"+sys.argv[1]+"_"+str(count)+".php"
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because because your class is wrong, try it with:

```
l = soup.findAll('tr',{'class' : r'\"kol\"'})
```

You can also get the tags like this:

```
l = soup.find('table', {'class': 'dataTable'}).tbody
```

Also, you should probably be using requests depending on which version of python you're using. Here's an example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.codechef.com/status/CIELAB?sort_by=All&sorting_order=asc&language=29&status=15&handle=&Submit=GO"
useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': useragent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
#l = soup.findAll('tr',{'class' : r'\"kol\"'})
l = soup.find('table', {'class': 'dataTable'}).tbody
```

Comment: `l = soup.findAll('tr',{'class' : r'\"kol\"'})` does not work. I still get an empty list.

Comment: @saqibns it works for me.. can you link your code? Also what python version do you have?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: @saqibns You don't have "html.parser" passed into BeautifulSoup

Comment: Actually, I did have it before. It was throwing the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` so I removed it.

Comment: @saqibns I think you might need BeautifulSoup4. once you've installed it, you should be able to do 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'. After that you can use the 'html.parser'.

Comment: Upgrading to BeautifulSoup4 did the job. :)